# How to put a image on a background behind some text

Tags: php, html, css

I am very new with HTML, PHP and CSS. So this is going to be a very 'simple' question.

I am still at the beginning of this webpage I want to try and design just for myself... I just want to know how to put the picture I use behind the text and I still want to use the black background color.

Here is the code I have:

```html
<html>

<head>
 <title>My Webpage</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="black">

<body>
<h1><font face="Forte"
    color="beige"
    size="10"
    <b>Header 1</b>
 </font>
</h1>
<h2><font face="Forte"
    color="beige"
       size="6">
    <b>Header 2</b>
 </font>
</h2>
<img src="WSBack.jpg" width="1250" height="300">
</body>

</html>
```

The image appears under the Words.

Please help?
Thanks

Comment: How are you learning HTML and CSS? Your HTML is very outdated, using obsolete attributes, and you don't have any CSS.

Comment: Anyway, here is my answer:
https://jsfiddle.net/scorpio777/6ztmo2so/5/